# Same query result the value on local but on server it shows null result

Tags: mysql

Below query run perfect on local phpmyadmin but not work on server phpmyadmin

```
select t.fk_user_id,
  t.target_month,
  t.target,
  e.ce_recruiter_id,
  e.billing_amount
from target t
left join closure_employee e
  on t.fk_user_id = e.ce_recruiter_id
  and month(t.target_month) = month(e.offer_date)
  and e.offer_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH)
where t.target_month > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH) and t.fk_user_id ='31'
```

LOCAL RESULT:

```
fk_user_id  target_month  target  ce_recruiter_id  billing_amount   
31           2013-07-01   100000    NULL            NULL
31           2013-08-01   100000    31          390000
31           2013-09-01   100000    31          208354
31           2013-10-01   120000    NULL            NULL
31           2013-11-01   120000    NULL            NULL
31           2013-12-01   120000    NULL            NULL
```

SERVER RESULT:

```
fk_user_id  target_month  target  ce_recruiter_id  billing_amount   
31           2013-07-01   100000    NULL            NULL
31           2013-08-01   100000    NULL            NULL
31           2013-09-01   100000    NULL            NULL
31           2013-10-01   120000    NULL            NULL
31           2013-11-01   120000    NULL            NULL
31           2013-12-01   120000    NULL            NULL
```

How i can get Local result on server.
Please help on this.

Comment: are you sure that your local data is the same as on the server side?

Comment: Given that the join predicate depends upon `NOW()`, are the times/timezones of the servers the same?

Comment: yes i am sure.
 provide some help

Comment: We appreciate that English may not be your first language, but "*provide some help*" comes across like an order and (to be quite frank) sounds rather rude.

Comment: @eggtal i have provided the time zone in my php config file. i do't no who i can provide the time zone in phpmyadmin.

Comment: in between transfer, source table might be changed by someone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can't give you the exact solution for your problem, because we don't know many things about your data and/or server configuration... but the easiest solution for you should be checking each condition that you use in your "where" statement seperately and find out which failed.

```
select e.* from target t 
left join closure_employee e on t.fk_user_id = e.ce_recruiter_id
where t.fk_user_id ='31'

select e.* from target t 
left join closure_employee e on t.fk_user_id = e.ce_recruiter_id and month(t.target_month) = month(e.offer_date)
where t.fk_user_id ='31'

select e.* from target t 
left join closure_employee e on t.fk_user_id = e.ce_recruiter_id and month(t.target_month) = month(e.offer_date) and e.offer_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH) 
where t.fk_user_id ='31'
```

and so on...
maybe this show you where the problem is

Comment: the last two query is showing null result on server but not on local.

Comment: so there is a problem with month(t.target_month) = month(e.offer_date) - execute "select t.target_month, e.offer_date from target t 
left join closure_employee e on t.fk_user_id = e.ce_recruiter_id
where t.fk_user_id ='31'" and look at the values

Answer (score 0):

first confirm that data is same. if yes than confirm that `data is committed or not` after any modifications at local.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure that your data is the same on both servers, then the only varying component in your query is the Now() function, so I guess the time is different here and there. Can you do a `select now()` on the server? (Or something like this.)

Also, I find it pretty strange that you use greater than operator (>) in a join. Do you really need that? AFAIC, it makes the query very unstable and unpredictable. I have a feeling that you intended to put it in the where clause.

Comment: Or maybe select now() on both machines and let us know the result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Thank you everyone especially @tuffkid.
The issue is that `offer_date` datatype is `varchar` so i have changed this into `datetime` and the issue is solved. i know this is silly mistake but i only focusing on the data in the table not on data type.